# CFWheels on Railo Stops working

Tags: tomcat, railo, cfwheels

I am running CFWheels, Railo on Amazon EC2 windows instance. Every few days the services of tomcat stops working and I have to restart it. It does not give me any error, it just displays "Service unavailable".

Anyone has any advice as far as where to check for issues or if this is a known issue that was addressed by someone before me? I haven't found anything online so far regarding this issue so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server i was running the application on was very low on RAM. I migrated the application on a different server and my issue was solved

Answer (score 0):

Is it a busy site, what is the memory usage.
are you perhaps exceeding the default jvm memory Settings?

Comment: No its not busy yet. I have it on my test domain for now so nobody but me and the client is accessing it at the moment. I haven't check the memory settings but I will do that. Thanks